# NeoVim configuratoin, VIMINIT MacOs question

Tags: vim, macvim, neovim

I just started using neovim on macos, I have created a init.vim file under ~/.config/nvim with my specified configurations however they are not applied everytime I launch nvim from the terminal. I thought that by making VIMINIT="~/.config/nvim/init.vim" a global variable it would fix the problem but every-time I launch nvim I get the error message saying.

Error detected while processing VIMINIT:
E33: No previous substitute regular expression
Press ENTER or type command to continue

If i press enter it resorts to the default nvim. Any ideas?

BTW if I type "$VIMINIT" in the terminal it does say permission denied. I dont know if this is helpful information. Thanks.

Comment: How did you install nvim, using homebrew?

Comment: Remove the global variable and show output of `:echo $MYVIMRC` in nvim.